# Problem with compare two String in powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, team-sites

I want to identify the type of web part by its name, in this case "news". If the title of the web part was the same as "string2" I would like to delete this web part. I don't understand why I keep getting false. I also tried compareTo.

If I write the value of the variable -> $webParts.Title

I get the string "Wiadmości" I do a comparison with the string "Wiadmości" I get false

```
$global:importFileName="sitesURL.csv"
functionmain()
{​​​​​​​​
$sites=import-csv$global:importFileName
$global:credentials=Get-Credential
ForEach($sitein$sites)
    {​​​​​​​​           
RemoveWebParts-sourceUrl$site.spUrl-location$pwd
    }​​​​​​​​
}​​​​​​​​
 
functionRemoveWebParts(){​​​​​​​​
Param( $sourceUrl
) Process{​​​​​​​​
Write-Host"###################### '$sourceUrl' ######################"-ForegroundColor Green
Connect-PnPOnline-Url$sourceUrl-Credentials$global:credentials
$page=Get-PnPClientSidePage-Identity"Home.aspx"

Write-Host"Search web parts:"-ForegroundColor Cyan
$webParts=$page.Controls

$loopCounter=0
foreach($webpartin$webparts) {​​​​​​​​
 
        [String] $string1=$webParts.Title
        [String] $string2="Wiadomości"

if( $string1-eq$string2) {​​​​​​​​
Remove-PnPClientSideComponent-Page$page-InstanceId$webpart.InstanceId
Write-Host"Deleted '$webpart.Title'"-ForegroundColor Green 
$loopCounter++
        }​​​​​​​​
    }​​​​​​​​
if($loopCounter-gt0){​​​​​​​​
Write-Host"Removed web parts '$loopCounter'"-ForegroundColor Green
    }​​​​​​​​
Write-Host"No items were found for removal "-ForegroundColor Yellow
}​​​​​​​​
}​​​​​​​​
Measure-Command {​​​​​​​​main}​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the code you pasted. It is missing alll spaces in each row. Can you re-paste the code, please?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the something is wrong with the accents or with casing. Or maybe there is some extra character in a string.

Always use single quotes when defining variables. Just in case there is a special character in your string:

```
[String] $string2='Wiadomości'
```

This is the best way to compare two strings:

```
[System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Compare($string1.trim(), $string2.trim())
```

Comment: There is a problem with the character encoding. The variable "Wiadomości" has a different number of bytes when printed than what I return from the web $webParts.Title. I am now retrieving the variables from a csv file and everything is fine.